# Button to load previous page with previous results

Tags: javascript, html, api

I've a page where you fill a form to search on YouTube API and returns some videos with buttons to go to another page with details about the video. Then there is a button to go back to previous page, but when clicked it returns the page as was open (Without any results). Is there a simple way to load the page with this results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the search key in [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) when the user clicks the video button. That way you can always get it back when you return to the previous page.